# Scrapy POST request not working - 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests, http-status-code-400

I am moving from python's `requests` library to `scrapy`, and I am having problems making a simple POST request. I am setting headers and payload as such:

```
headers = {
    'Accept':'*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language':'en_US',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length':'151',
    'content-type':'application/json',
    'Cookie':cookie,
    'Host':host,
    'Origin':origin,
    'Referer':referer,
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36',
    'x-csrf-token':token
}

payload = {"targetLocation":{"latitude":lat,"longitude":lng}}
```

And then making the request like this:

```
def start_requests(self):
    u = self.url
    yield scrapy.Request(u, method='POST',
                            callback=self.parse_httpbin,
                            errback=self.errback_httpbin,
                            body=json.dumps(self.payload),
                            headers=self.headers)
```

And that keeps on giving me 400 status. If I make the request using the exact same headers and payload with the `requests` library, it gives me 200 status and returns a json, as expected.

```
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload), verify=False)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You really shouldn't set your own `Content-Length` header. Most libraries will calculate that for you. if `scrapy` is sending it twice, the server is *required* by the specification to return a 400.

Comment: That was it! Works like a charm now. Thanks! :)

Comment: @sigmavirus24 this answer is great, please post it in the answer area.

Comment: I've added an answer to that effect, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of these headers that you have in your request are not advisable for using general purpose HTTP libraries. Most libraries will generate these themselves:

- Host
- Content-Length

Specifically, the HTTP RFCs specify very clearly that any time a `Content-Length` header is sent more than once (which Scrapy might be doing) then the response *must* be a 400. Requests, likely doesn't set it's own Content-Length header and defers to yours.

Comment: you just saved me several hours of debugging ... I had `content-length` in headers and it started giving me http 400 ... I then tried same on my localhost url with simple one index.php file, it gave http 400 as well, then I came to google and ended up on your answer ... thanks :)